# How does 'Bull I' Th' Thorn Inn' translate into standard English?

Tags: dialects

I am currently staying briefly in Stockport. Among the vast array of historical education that the town offers, is a most refreshing feature, given the current heat wave in North-west England. That is Robinsons' Brewery. I note from their museum that one of the their pubs, at Hurdlow in Derbyshire is called the Bull I' Th' Thorn Inn.

I feel certain that @Edwin Ashworth will be able to explain that.

http://www.bulliththorninn.robinsonsbrewery.com/contact

Of course I am supposing it means 'Bull in the thorn'. But interestingly the letter 'I' is written as a capital in the pub name.

And what might be the precise pronunciation in the Derbyshire accent?

Comment: What about asking about this at the Inn? I understand you are there now!!

Comment: @Josh61 No I am in Stockport. But thanks, you have given me a good excuse for a visit and another jar of the *Old Tom* ale. I just have to persuade my wife to take a detour on the way home. Might be difficult when she discovers what it is for!

Comment: I can't do better than suggest that Janus' findings are probably right, and that 'Hurdlow House' became known as 'Hurdlow Thorn' because of local geographical features (cf Moreton in Marsh and Stow-on-the-Wold). Linguistically. However, as regards breweries ...

Comment: Thornbridge Hall is in Buxton. Not sure how close that would be, a few miles? nor whether there is any connection.

Comment: In this [1895 Directory of Derbyshire](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=eD0JAAAAIAAJ&q=%22Bull+In+The+Thorn+inn%22&dq=%22Bull+In+The+Thorn+inn%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OgvRU4eIMfCw7AaU9oHoAg&redir_esc=y), one William Wigley is listed as the "vict" [victualler?] at the ***Bull-in-the-Thorn Inn*** in Hurdlow. The latter-day elisions are just an attempt to add "local colour" to attract the tourist trade.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason why it would not be something simple, like

- bull -> male cow
- i' -> in
- th' -> the
- thorn -> prickly bushes
- inn -> pub

So **[the] pub [named] *the male bovine [that got stuck] in prickly bushes***.

As to *why* pubs and inns are given such names, that would be more fodder for a psychologist than a linguist I'm afraid...

Comment: According to [this ghost tour site](http://www.hauntedevenings.co.uk/product/ghost-hunt-wortley-top-forge-260914-copy), it's a mixture of two earlier names of the house: _The Bull_ (original name of the inn from the 1400s onwards) and _Hurdlow Thorn_ from the 1600s onwards. No idea how reliable that is, though—it's just from a quick Google search.

Comment: Well, the pub's been there since 1472. I'm not sure they had psychologists then! It hadn't escaped me that it might mean 'Bull in the  thorn', but I am intrigued as to the history.

Comment: @WS2 - that the did not _have_ psychologists doesn't mean they wouldn't have _needed_ them...

Comment: @oerkelens In the fifteenth century they used axes where we use psychologists - cheaper!

Answer (score 2):

There is a wide variety of pub names in Britain, from the [fairly sensible](http://www.innsignsociety.com/names.htm) to the [downright bonkers](http://www.readersdoglist.com/pubnames.html).

While many pub names include animals, there is a significant subset that refer to some action of the animal.  This is particularly true if it refers to some famous local event - either real or imaginary.

One feature of the dialect of Yorkshire and, to a lesser extent, Derbyshire is the elision of many conjunctions and prepositions.  The most famous is *T'* for *The* but includes *I'* for *In*.

So the sign is just exaggerating *The Bull In The Thorn Bush* to attract passing trade.  It would be pronounced as it is spelt on the sign.

Comment: See @Janus comment

Answer (score -1):

Pronounced: bull inthorn its common up north to use the word 'inth' or 'ith' instead of saying 'in the'

Comment: I'd have said it was pronounced *Bull int' thorn*